# A haskell floating point calculation anomaly?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, type-conversion, precision, largenumber

**2022 Update**: This bug was filed as a GHC ticket and is now fixed: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17231 so this is no longer an issue.

Using ghci 8.6.5

I want to calculate the square root of an Integer input, then round it to the bottom and return an Integer.

```
square :: Integer -> Integer
square m = floor $ sqrt $ fromInteger m
```

It works.
The problem is, for this specific big number as input:

4141414141414141*4141414141414141

I get a wrong result.

Putting my function aside, I test the case in ghci:

```
> sqrt $ fromInteger $ 4141414141414141*4141414141414141
4.1414141414141405e15
```

wrong... right?

BUT SIMPLY

```
> sqrt $ 4141414141414141*4141414141414141
4.141414141414141e15
```

which is more like what I expect from the calculation...

In my function I have to make some type conversion, and I reckon fromIntegral is the way to go. So, using that, my function gives a wrong result for the 4141...41 input.

I can't figure out what ghci does implicitly in terms of type conversion, right before running sqrt. Because ghci's conversion allows for a correct calculation.

Why I say this is an anomaly: the problem does not occur with other numbers like 5151515151515151 or 3131313131313131 or 4242424242424242 ...

Is this a Haskell bug?

Comment: It looks like floating point overflow.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This seems like a clear bug: `fromInteger $ 4141414141414141*4141414141414141` produces `1.7151311090705025e31`, but `1.7151311090705027e31` is a valid `Double` and is closer to the correct integer `17151311090705026668707274767881`. So `fromInteger` is to blame here, not rounding!

Comment: For exact bignum square roots (i.e. staying within `Integer` and never passing through `Double`), you might like [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.9.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Squares.html).

Comment: in ghci 7.8.3 I get same correct result for both calculations.

Comment: IMO, all languages should care of ISO/IEC 10967-2 (Language Independent Arithmetic (LIA), Part II, 1994) which convers float<->int conversions including case of unbounded integer. See http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG11/docs/n462.pdf §5.4.3. At least, level of conformance to 10967 should be reported.

Comment: I filed a GHC bug here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17231

Comment: Thank you all for the input. Learned a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: You can use `(read . show)` instead of `fromInteger` to circumvent the rounding issue. This is how `dhall` implements its `Integer/toDouble` operation.

Comment: sjakobi, now that's a neat workaround. thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TLDR

It comes down to how one converts an `Integer` value to a `Double` that is not exactly representable. Note that this can happen not just because `Integer` is too big (or too small), but `Float` and `Double` values by design "skip around" integral values as their magnitude gets larger. So, not every integral value in the range is exactly representable either. In this case, an implementation has to pick a value based on the rounding-mode. Unfortunately, there are multiple candidates; and what you are observing is that the candidate picked by Haskell gives you a worse numeric result.

## Expected Result

Most languages, including Python, use what's known as "round-to-nearest-ties-to-even" rounding mechanism; which is the default IEEE754 rounding mode and is typically what you would get unless you explicitly set a rounding mode when issuing a floating-point related instruction in a compliant processor. Using Python as the "reference" here, we get:

```py
>>> float(long(4141414141414141)*long(4141414141414141))
1.7151311090705027e+31
```

I haven't tried in other languages that support so called big-integers, but I'd expect most of them would give you this result.

## How Haskell converts `Integer` to `Double`

Haskell, however, uses what's known as *truncation*, or round-towards-zero. So you get:

```hs
*Main> (fromIntegral $ 4141414141414141*4141414141414141) :: Double
1.7151311090705025e31
```

Turns out this is a "worse" approximation in this case (cf. to the Python produced value above), and you get the unexpected result in your original example.

The call to `sqrt` is really red-herring at this point.

## Show me the code

It all originates from this code: (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.2.0/docs/src/GHC.Integer.Type.html#doubleFromInteger)

```hs
doubleFromInteger :: Integer -> Double#
doubleFromInteger (S# m#) = int2Double# m#
doubleFromInteger (Jp# bn@(BN# bn#))
    = c_mpn_get_d bn# (sizeofBigNat# bn) 0#
doubleFromInteger (Jn# bn@(BN# bn#))
    = c_mpn_get_d bn# (negateInt# (sizeofBigNat# bn)) 0#
```

which in turn calls: (https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/integer-gmp/cbits/wrappers.c#L183-L190):

```
/* Convert bignum to a `double`, truncating if necessary
 * (i.e. rounding towards zero).
 *
 * sign of mp_size_t argument controls sign of converted double
 */
HsDouble
integer_gmp_mpn_get_d (const mp_limb_t sp[], const mp_size_t sn,
                       const HsInt exponent)
{
...
```

which *purposefully* says the conversion is done rounding-toward zero.

So, that explains the behavior you get.

## Why does Haskell do this?

None of this explains why Haskell uses round-towards-zero for integer-to-double conversion. I'd strongly argue that it should use the default rounding mode, i.e., round-nearest-ties-to-even. I can't find any mention whether this was a conscious choice, and it at least disagrees with what Python does. (Not that I'd consider Python the gold standard, but it does tend to get these things right.)

My best guess is it was just coded that way, without a conscious choice; but perhaps other people familiar with the history of numeric programming in Haskell can remember better.

## What to do

Interestingly, I found the following discussion dating all the way back to 2008 as a Python bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue3166. Apparently, Python used to do the wrong thing here as well, but they fixed the behavior. It's hard to track the exact history, but it appears Haskell and Python both made the same mistake; Python recovered, but it went unnoticed in Haskell. If this was a conscious choice, I'd like to know why.

So, that's where it stands. I'd recommend opening a GHC ticket so it can be at least documented properly that this is the "chosen" behavior; or better, fix it so that it uses the default rounding mode instead.

## Update:

GHC ticket opened: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17231

## 2022 Update:

This is now fixed in GHC; at least as of GHC 9.2.2; but possibly earlier:

```
GHCi, version 9.2.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> (fromIntegral $ 4141414141414141*4141414141414141) :: Double
1.7151311090705027e31
```

Answer (score 6):

Not all `Integer`s are exactly representable as `Double`s. For those that aren't, `fromInteger` is in the bad position of needing to make a choice: which `Double` should it return? I can't find anything in the Report which discusses what to do here, wow!

One obvious solution would be to return a `Double` that has no fractional part and which represents the integer with the smallest absolute difference from the original of any `Double` that exists. Unfortunately this appears not to be the decision made by GHC's `fromInteger`.

Instead, GHC's choice is to return the `Double` with the largest magnitude that does not exceed the magnitude of the original number. So:

```
> 17151311090705026844052714160127 :: Double
1.7151311090705025e31
> 17151311090705026844052714160128 :: Double
1.7151311090705027e31
```

(Don't be fooled by how short the displayed number is in the second one: the `Double` there is the exact representation of the integer on the line above it; the digits stop there because there are enough to uniquely identify a single `Double`.)

Why does this matter for you? Well, the true answer to `4141414141414141*4141414141414141` is:

```
> 4141414141414141*4141414141414141
17151311090705026668707274767881
```

If `fromInteger` converted this to the nearest `Double`, as in plan (1) above, it would choose `1.7151311090705027e31`. But since it returns the largest `Double` less than the input as in plan (2) above, and `17151311090705026844052714160128` is technically bigger, it returns the less accurate representation `1.7151311090705025e31`.

Meanwhile, `4141414141414141` itself is exactly representable as a `Double`, so if you first convert to `Double`, then square, you get `Double`'s semantics of choosing the representation that is closest to the correct answer, hence plan (1) instead of plan (2).

This explains the discrepancy in `sqrt`'s output: doing your computations in `Integer` first and getting an exact answer, then converting to `Double` at the last second, paradoxically is less accurate than converting to `Double` immediately and doing your computations with rounding the whole way, because of how `fromInteger` does its conversion! Ouch.

I suspect a patch to modify `fromInteger` to do something better would be looked on favorably by GHCHQ; in any case I know *I* would look favorably on it!

Comment: Your analysis is supported by z3. Funny this never came up before!

Comment: ghci 7.8.3. returns same correct result in both cases. (Windows7  64 bit)